# How to get a Gsuite Marketplace App installation record

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I published an app in Gsuite Marketplace, I would like to know if I can get any record of the installations performed, maybe some user data (like emails or at least the domain).
I've searched in the web and browsed the admin console but I can't find the way.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in the marketplace faq, and there's not a direct way through the admin console, but instead all details can be obtained from the Licensing API.

Source: [G Suite Marketplace FAQ](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/faq#how_can_i_get_information_about_app_usage)